# How to write a values around a circle using QPainter class without rotating?

Tags: qt, draw, qpainter

The question is simple ! I want something like this using `QPainter` class. 
[image]

i dont want values to be rotated. but using `QPainter::rotate` method I am getting the values like this(rotated format).

[image]

Can someone help me to draw the circle with values like the first image using `QPainter`

Comment: Is it a circle or an ellipse?

Answer (score 4):

Here is the simplest code on how I would do it. Assuming I am painting in the paint event of a widget:

```
#define PI 3.14159265

[..]

void Widget::paintEvent(QPaintEvent *event)
{
    QPainter painter(this);

    QPoint center = rect().center();
    painter.drawEllipse(center, 2, 2);
    const int radius = 100;
    // Draw semicircle with texts on every 30".
    for (double i = .0; i <= 180.0; i += 30.0) {
        QPoint p(center.x() + radius * cos(i * PI / 180.0),
                 center.y() - radius * sin(i * PI / 180.0));
        painter.drawText(p, QString::number(i));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

**Draw a text without formulas along any path**

[image: Arc]  [image: Cubic]
**Create a path**
There is a class `QPainterPath` using which you can draw any path using a bunch of methods.
In your case it's possible to use `arcTo`.

```
QPainterPath path;
path.arcTo(rect, 210, -240.0);
```

**Calculate a starting point**
There is a little difficulty there: a path has a starting point. If you call `arcTo` it will create a line to the beginning of the arc and then draw the arc. So you need to call `moveTo` and pass the starting point of the arc as an argument. But where you can get it? Calculate using a formula of an arc? No. Of cource it's possible to experiment and set an approximate point or open a book and find a formula of any curve, but there is an easy way to know a starting point: draw a zero-size curve and get the last point of it:

```
QPainterPath initialPath; 
initialPath.arcTo(rect, 210, 0);
path.moveTo(initialPath.currentPosition());
```

**Draw a text**
When you have this path you can get any point of the path using `pointAtPercent` and use `drawText`   to paint a text there.
Here is a code to draw an arc and numbers below:

```
    QPainter p(this);

    p.drawArc(rect(), 210 * 16, -240 * 16);

    QRectF rect(20, 20, width() - 40, height() - 40);

    QPainterPath initialPath;
    initialPath.arcTo(rect, 210, 0);

    QPainterPath path;
    path.moveTo(initialPath.currentPosition());
    path.arcTo(rect, 210, -240.0);

    for (int i = 0; i <= 10; i += 1)
    {
        p.drawText(path.pointAtPercent((qreal)i / 10), QString::number(i));
    }
```